# Minimal Trigonometry

Tags: trigonometry

Triangle ABC has angle BAC given and the lengths |AB| and |AC| satisfy 
$$|AB|\cdot |AC| = 1.$$ Let AD be the angle bisector of BAC. Express the length |AD| as a function of the length |AB|.

I keep running into an issue where I need the length of one more side or the measure of another angle to come up with a formula. Can anyone supply a solution to this problem?

Answer (score 2):

The area of the triangle is
$T
=\frac12 |AB|\ |AC| \sin(BAC)
$.
Therefore
$T
=\frac12 \sin(BAC)
$.

Since we know
$\angle BAC$,
we know
$\theta = \frac12 \angle BAC$.

The area of
$BAD$
is
$\frac12 |AB| |AD| \sin \theta$
and the area of
$DAC$
is
$\frac12 |AC| |AD| \sin \theta$.
The sum of these
is the area of the triangle,
so,
canceling the $\frac12$,
$\sin(BAC)
=|AB| |AD| \sin \theta + |AC| |AD| \sin \theta
= |AD| \sin \theta(|AB| + |AC|)
$.

Therefore

$\begin{array}\\
|AD|
&=(|AB| + |AC|)\frac{\sin(BAC)}{\sin \theta}\\
&=(|AB| + |AC|)\frac{\sin(2\theta)}{\sin \theta}\\
&=(|AB| + |AC|)\frac{2\sin(\theta)\cos(\theta)}{\sin \theta}\\
&=2(|AB| + |AC|)\cos(\theta)\\
&=2(|AB| + \frac1{|AB|})\cos(\theta)\\
\end{array}
$

Comment: Hello，I think you have complete this answer,because $|AC|=\dfrac{1}{|AB|}$

Comment: But I don't know either one, just that they are reciprocals. If you can complete my answer, I'll upvote you.

Comment: you can see this OP Qustion, find the $AD$ as a function of the length |AB|

Comment: But I don't know BD and CD.

Comment: you have  $|AD|=2(|AB|+|AC|)\cos{\theta}$, because $\theta $ is give

Comment: You are right. I was correct without realizing it! Duh!

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

> $\frac{AD}{\sin B}=\frac{BD}{\sin \frac A2}=\frac{ac}{(b+c)\sin \frac A2}$, and $[ABC]=\frac 12bc\sin A=\frac 12 ca\sin B\implies ca\sin B=\sin A$.

Comment: What are a,b,c in your hint?

Comment: We usually denote the sidelengths $BC,CA,AB$ with $a,b,c$ respectively. ^^